# How to print a part from the array list with for loop in java

Tags: java, arrays

I'm a newbie of programming languages.

i have a code

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class arr1{

  public static void main(String args[]){
    String str = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "please choose a array : ");
    int n = Integer.parseInt(str);

    Integer list[] = {1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19};

    for(n=0; n<=list.length; n++){
      if (list[n]==0){
        JOptionPane.showInputDialog(":", list[0]);
      } else if (list[n]==1){
        JOptionPane.showInputDialog(":", list[1]);
      } else if (list[n]==2){
        JOptionPane.showInputDialog(":", list[2]);
      } else if (list[n]==3){
        JOptionPane.showInputDialog(":", list[3]);
      } else if (list[n]==4){
        JOptionPane.showInputDialog(":", list[4]);
      } else if (list[n]==5){
        JOptionPane.showInputDialog(":", list[5]);
      } else if (list[n]==6){
        JOptionPane.showInputDialog(":", list[6]);
      } else if (list[n]==7){
        JOptionPane.showInputDialog(":", list[7]);
      } else if (list[n]==8){
        JOptionPane.showInputDialog(":", list[8]);
      } else if (list[n]==9){
        JOptionPane.showInputDialog(":", list[9]);
      }
    }
  }

}
```

the output not as expected.

if i insert the "n" input is 3, the output should be

```
the output : 1, 3, 5
```

else if i insert the "n" input is 5, the output should be

```
the output : 1, 3, 5, 7, 9
```

Thanks in advance and hope anyone can helps me without a downvote cause it's really basic question.

Comment: If you are not familiar enough with Java you should start with the tutorials: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/ and begin with input and output in a terminal instead of graphical application.

Comment: While not technically an answer, I would like to point out that you set the `n` variable in your for loop back to 0, so it always loops through the whole array.

Comment: @EInherjar yap!! i really had low logical level, i get it from the answered section

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just loop until `n`:

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    JOptionPane.showInputDialog(":", list[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should print it like this

```
for(int i =0; i < n; i++) {
    //print list[i]
}
```